# SAS arrays: How to get sum, max, min of a subset of an array

Tags: arrays, sas

I want to get the sum, max, and/or min of a subset of an array.

In SAS, you can say:

```
x = max(of v5-v10);
```

where v5 through v10 are variables

But you cannot say:

```
array v[20];
i = 5;
x = max(of v[i]-v[i+5];
```

It doesn't understand that v[i]-v[i+5] is a range of variables. Is there anyother way to do it what would work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either iterate over the elements of the array:

```
data max ;
  array v{20} ;
  i = 5 ;
  vmax = . ;
  do n = i to i+5 ;
    vmax = max(vmax,v{n}) ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Or create a new array which contains just the elements you require:

```
%LET I = 5 ;
data max ;
  array v{*} v&I-v%EVAL(&I+5) ;
  vmax = max(of v{*}) ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the first one; the second one wouldn't have worked for me because i was the index of a dataset do loop. I especially like the idea of setting vmax to .

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
array a(*) _numeric_;
do i=1 to dim(a);
if a(i) = . then a(i) = 0; //this replaces mssing for 0´s but you can implement any logic here
end;
drop i;
```